# Capacitor SQLite: getArray calls without a default value will return null in Capacitor 5 instead of an empty array to match iOS behavior

Tags: android, sqlite, logcat, capacitor

I am using Ionic Capacitor SQLite and I am getting this warning in my Android Studio Logcat logs:

`getArray calls without a default value will return null in Capacitor 5 instead of an empty array to match iOS behavior`

Why does it come, when I am not even using the getArray method?
perhaps because: https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite is using it? But still in my opinion warnings from libraries shouldn't appear in the logcat logs with the log-config level:info package:mine

Should I be worried about it?

I am currently having a bug in my program so I am wondering whether this is the cause.

This is popping up in 50 times (50 rows of this same warning below each other) in my logcat console